# Play Framework PathBindable with Dependency Injection

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.5

I'm migrating a Scala Play application to 2.5 and am currently moving my components to dependency injection. There's one place left where I'm at a loss how to do it though. I have a PathBindable implicit conversion defined in the companion object:

```
object Task {
  implicit def pathBindable(implicit stringBinder: PathBindable[String]) =
    new PathBindable[Task] {
       ...
    }
}
```

The implementation of the PathBindable needs to look up the object from a repository, but I haven't found a way to dependency-inject the repository here. As a workaround I'm using the now deprecated Play object:

```
val tasks = Play.application(Play.current).injector.instanceOf[TasksRepository]
```

Any ideas how to solve this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Lightbend Engineer Greg Methvin](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/play-framework/b1fF2EdmCJ8/F2mX1EflJAAJ), PathBindables should only depend on the state in the path. The reason is that the code [runs on the IO thread](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRequestBinders#PathBindable) and should therefore be fast and not block.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the only way you can access stuff like this in objects.

A better idea is to create a the transformer like this:

```
class TaskPathBinder @Inject() ( tasks : TaskRepository ) extends PathBindable[Task]{
  // implementiation
}
```

and than inject it in services like this

```
class NeedsTaskPathBinder @Inject() ( service : SomeSerive ) (implicit taskPathBinder : TaskPathBinder) {

   ... 

}
```

Hope the you get the idea.

Comment: Hm, the problem is that the implicit needs to be available to the routes so that I can use it there: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.PathBindable