# How to inject a component into a PathBindable

Tags: java, playframework, dependency-injection, guice, playframework-2.4

I want to create a similar `PathBindable` as the one presented [in the documentation](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.x/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/PathBindable.java) for one of my entities.

The problem is that I am not using Ebean and so I need to inject a service with Guice in order to find my user by email.

I tried with the several injection types (field, setter, constructor) and it does not work, my service is not injected. I suppose it is due to the "*The only requirement is that the class provides a noarg constructor*" written in the JavaDoc of `PathBindable`...

Is it possible to achieve what I want to do ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422378/play-framework-pathbindable-with-dependency-injection